# Integrate existing database into Jenkins user database

Tags: database, jenkins

I am using Role based strategy plugin in Jenkins to manage user and role in Jenkins.

I have an existing database of my own that contain the user and the permission to access project.

Is it possible to integrate database into Jenkins such that the users, roles ,permission and project are from my own database instead of manually creating the users, permissions, roles and project?

If it is possible, how should i do it?

I have tried manually creating the users, roles in Jenkins based on the database i have and it worked.

I am thinking if there is a more efficient way to create the users and roles in Jenkins from my own database.

For eg

my own database contains 2 table.

First table is the user table which contains the user and roles column

(User1, Developer)
...

Second table is the permission table which state what each role can access
and has the roles, read, write, modify column

(Developer, true, true true)

(Project Manager, true, false, false)

All these information should be integrated into Jenkins users, roles, project table.

Answer (score 0):

Check what they say in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/232871/369810):

> Jenkins works on files, and not in a database

So you have a little handicap for this.

My best idea for solving this is to use [OAuth](https://oauth.net/) plugins with it.

OAuth handles the login on multiple applications/platforms with just one account as github one or google one do. This types of libraries also prevent you from doing bad and insecure practices that we usually do when coding Login and secured functions, as they are developed correctly.

If you follow the recommendations for the implementation of those OAuth flows, you will have it working like a charm.

Those are for example two dedicated Jenkins plugis for OAuth

- [Google OAuth Plugin](http://ttps://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Google+OAuth+Plugin)
- [GitHub OAuth Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-oauth-plugin)

So, if the users on your database are created as OAuth, you will be  able to use them on near every platform around.

I hope this clarifies to you.